# Update Robolectric 2.4: Getting application tag error for library projects in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, robolectric

Stacktrace of error i am getting after updating robolectric with 2.4

Any Solution?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing required <application/> element in .\..\google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:226)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing required <application/> element in .\..\google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.parseAndroidManifest(AndroidManifest.java:155)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getPackageName(AndroidManifest.java:474)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getResourcePath(AndroidManifest.java:517)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getIncludedResourcePaths(AndroidManifest.java:522)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getIncludedResourcePaths(AndroidManifest.java:524)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:635)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:627)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:67)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:440)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:222)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you choose an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Roboletric 2.4 would check  tag for library projects.

You can refer to this official link: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/1309

It has a workaround to resolve this issue.

Comment: More specifically, [this is the work-around](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/1309#issuecomment-62593267).

Comment: i am getting the same error for ViewPagerIndicator with Roboelectric 2.4any sugeestions Pls?

Comment: I found someone create issue for roboletric
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1602

however, it seems there is no enough information about this.
If possible, you might be able to share your log for erd to debug.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround we need to extend org.robolectric.AndroidManifest in our project, removed the check for the  element, and override createAppManifest(...) in a custom test runner.

https://github.com/mapzen/mapzen-android-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/org/robolectric/MapzenAndroidManifest.java#L163

https://github.com/mapzen/mapzen-android-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mapzen/open/support/MapzenTestRunner.java#L100